# Помогите написать программу. Используемое ПО - Паскаль

Tags: pascal

Дан набор из N целых положительных чисел. Необходимо определить,  с какой цифры чаще всего начинается десятичная запись чисел этого набора. Если таких цифр несколько, необходимо вывести наибольшую из них. Напишите эффективную по времени и по памяти программу для решения этой задачи.
 **Описание входных и выходных данных**: В первой строке входных данных задаётся количество чисел N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000). В каждой из последующих N строк записано одно натуральное число, не превышающее 10000. Пример входных данных: 5 15 417 125 32 4801 Пример выходных данных для приведённого выше примера входных данных: 4 Десятичная запись чисел заданного набора чаще всего – по 2 раза – начинается с цифр 1 и 4, в ответе выведена бóльшая из них.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации, добавьте описание конкретных проблем, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Один вопрос: как описать на языке программирования алгоритм определения первой цифры числа? Проблема в том, что 1<=N<=1000 и через функцию mod или div бессмысленно выделять первую цифру, ведь число может быть одно-, дву-, трех-, четырехзначным.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
program digits;
var
  N: integer; // Количество вводимых чисел
  i: integer; // Счетчик
  x: integer; // Каждое отдельное число
  max_v, max_i: integer; // Наибольшее количество чисел и само число
  score: array[1..9] of integer; // Количество первых цифр
begin
  // Инициализация массива
  for i := 1 to 9 do
    score[i] := 0;

  Write('Количество чисел (N): ');
  Read(N);
  for i := 1 to N do
    begin
      Write('Введите число #', i, ': ');
      Read(x);
      while (x > 10) do
        x := x div 10;
      score[x] := score[x] + 1;
    end;

  max_i := 1;
  max_v := score[1];
  for i := 2 to 9 do
    begin
      if max_v <= score[i] then
        begin
          max_i := i;
          max_v := score[i];
        end;
    end;

  Write('Наибольшее количество чисел начинается с цифры "', max_i, '" и встречается "', max_v, '" раз.');
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!